# XSD File viewer/website which shows a tree/nested elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm looking for a simple XSD viewer which takes some raw text/file, and generates a tree of the XSD file whereby each element can be easily toggled using +/- buttons. Is there any such thing available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saved the XML fragment I found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) as x.xsd, and opened the file from Firefox.

I see this foldable tree structure.

[image]

Hope I understood your question well.